# Select tag having a dot with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, lxml

How can select and modify the tag `<Tagwith.dot>` with some other text using beautifulsoup? If its not possible with beautifulsoup then what is the next best library for xml document edit and creation, would be lxml?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

stra = """
<body>
<Tagwith.dot>Text inside tag with dot</Tagwith.dot>
</body>"""
soup = bs(stra)
```

Desired XML:

```
<body>
<Tagwith.dot>Edited text</Tagwith.dot>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BS4 assumes and converts all the tags to lower case. The below code works fine. Provide the tag name in lower case.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

stra = """
<body>
<Tagwith.dot>Text inside tag with dot</Tagwith.dot>
</body>"""
soup = bs(stra, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all('tagwith.dot'))
```

Output:

```
[<tagwith.dot>Text inside tag with dot</tagwith.dot>]
```

Comment: I see. I thought it's not working because `"."` might be related to a css class syntax. Perfect. It's working now with `tag_string.lower()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to achieve what you want as follows

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

stra = """
<body>
<Tagwith.dot>Text inside tag with dot</Tagwith.dot>
</body>"""

#Read xml string and convert to xml object
xml_obj = ET.fromstring(stra)

#Iterate through elements
for elem in xml_obj:
    #If tag is found, modify the text
    if elem.tag == 'Tagwith.dot':
        elem.text = 'Edited text'

#Print updated xml object as a string
print(ET.tostring(xml_obj).decode())
```

The output will be

```
<body>
<Tagwith.dot>Edited text</Tagwith.dot>
</body>
```

Comment: Is there a way to directly select it as well, instead of iterating and finding it manually, I'd rather let the library do the recursive iteration if the tag is nested deep inside.

Comment: Sure,  let me check up on how we can achieve it @Zid